# The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "PKIX path building failed:

Tags: java, sql, intellij-idea

I'm new to SQL(Microsoft SQL Server Management) and I am trying to connect it with IntelliJ

I am getting the following error:
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target".

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MyJDBC {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    String  connectionURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:10020;databaseName=mydatabase;user=me;password=random_password";
    try {
        System.out.print("Connecting to the server......");
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL))   {
            System.out.println("Connected to the Server.");
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("I am not connected to the Server");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I have this on my lib
[LIB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlaRU.png)

Any help is appreciated it!

Comment: Are you trying to connect IntelliJ IDEA itself (https://i.imgur.com/udfl01m.png), or connect from your source code? For the first case, see the workarounds from https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-13313

Answer (score 38):

Add `encrypt=true` and `trustServerCertificate=true` to connection url.

```
String  connectionURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:10020;databaseName=mydatabase;user=me;password=random_password;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true";
```

Microsoft Blog Reference - [link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/pkix-path-building-failed-unable-to-find-valid-certification/ba-p/2591304)

Find below excerpt from it -

> This is an issue in Java Certificate Store. As a quick workaround, if
> you enable TrustServerCertificate=True in the connection string, the
> connection from JDBC succeeds. When TrustServerCertificate is set to
> true, the transport layer will use SSL to encrypt the channel and
> bypass walking the certificate chain to validate trust. If
> TrustServerCertificate is set to true and encryption is turned on, the
> encryption level specified on the server will be used even if Encrypt
> is set to false. The connection will fail otherwise. However, for
> security considerations, it is not recommended to bypass the
> certificate validation. Hence, to address the issue, follow the steps
> below to change the connection string and import the required
> certificates.
>
> Change the connection string to point to the Java certificate path
>
> `String connectionUrl =  "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" +`
> `"databaseName=AdventureWorks;integratedSecurity=true;" +`
> `"encrypt=true; trustServerCertificate=false;" +`
> `"trustStore= C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\lib\cacert;trustStorePassword=changeit";`
>
> Import all the certificates mentioned in this [document](https://www.microsoft.com/pki/mscorp/cps/default.htm).
>
> Note: To import above certificates into the keystore cacerts, please
> use below command and please note you must mention truststore and
> truststore password in the connection string to successfully connect.
> Steps to import missing certificates in Java Certificate Store
>
> Download all the certs from here, store them in a location on client
> host and then use keytool utility to import these certificates into
> the truststore. Please follow the below steps:
>
> Save all the certificates from the above MS doc. Keytool utility is in
> the bin folder of your default Java location (C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin). You need to use command prompt to navigate
> to that location. Then you can use the keytool command to import the
> certificate previously saved.  When prompted for password insert the
> key in the password as “changeit”
>
> Example of commands:
>
> `keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -alias TLS1 -file`
> `"C:\Users\Documents\Microsoft RSA TLS CA 01.crt" -keystore "C:\Program`
> `Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\lib\security\cacerts"`
>
> `keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -alias TLS2 -file`
> `"C:\Users\Documents\Microsoft RSA TLS CA 02.crt" -keystore "C:\Program`
> `Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\lib\security\cacerts"`

Comment: another ref link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-with-ssl-encryption?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I had this issue with Apache Hop. This worked for me: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=MyDB;user=MyName;password=MyPwd;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true

Answer (score 2):

Below worked for me:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://Host;trustServerCertificate=true;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=NTLM
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)".

```
import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBContext {

    protected Connection connection;

    public DBContext() {
        try {
            // Edit URL , username, password to authenticate with your MS SQL Server
            String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName= Trading2022";
            String username = "sa";
            String password = "221202";
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```