# Problems using jooq trial version

Tags: jooq

I registered for the free trial of the 3.18.7 express, downloaded and maven-installed the libraries.

My pom.xml is below. On running the compile target I get the following error "*unable to find valid certification path to requested target*"

I have used JOOQ with postgresql with no problems, this is connecting to a MS SQL Express server. Is this a JOOQ issue or an MS SQL server issue?

The JDBC string has been tested using intellij.

Any thoughts?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.1.5

```
<groupId>com.chiralcloud</groupId>
<artifactId>chiralcloud</artifactId>
<version>0.0.10</version>

<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jooq.trial</groupId>
        <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
        <version>3.18.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- These may not be required, unless you use the GenerationTool manually for code generation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jooq.trial</groupId>
        <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
        <version>3.18.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jooq.trial</groupId>
        <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
        <version>3.18.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.2.jre17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>com/chiralcloud/database/**</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
                    <version>11.2.2.jre17</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <jdbc>
                    <driver>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.0.83\test:60062;databaseName=Annex</url>
                    <user>sa</user>
                    <password>######</password>
                </jdbc>
                <generator>
                    <database>
                        <name>org.jooq.meta.</name>
                        <includes>.*</includes>
                        <inputSchema>public</inputSchema>
                    </database>
                    <target>
                        <packageName>com.chiralcloud.database</packageName>
                        <directory>target/generated-sources/jooq</directory>
                    </target>
                </generator>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate of this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/73291498/521799

Comment: That solved the jdbc driver issue, now I get the following "[ERROR] NoSuchFieldError may happen when the jOOQ Open Source Edition (Maven groupId 'org.jooq') is used with a commercial SQLDialect. Use an appropriate groupId instead: 'org.jooq.trial', 'org.jooq.trial-java-8', 'org.jooq.trial-java-11', 'org.jooq.pro', 'org.jooq.pro-java-8', or 'org.jooq.pro-java-11'". The pom is definitely using the ".trial" groupId, is the maven plugin correct?

Comment: All sorted now, just a question of getting the maven plugin name correct, I couldn't use org.jooq.trial, I had to use org.jooq.trial-java-8. Then the schema name was also wrong, using a previous project's name. Many thanks